# Python - Trying to call a function from another file (using python-pptx)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

I have a build a Python script that uses `python-pptx` module to generate a powerpoint deck. The code runs over 300 lines of code due to various formatting. So I plan to split into several sub-functions so that it is easy to maintain in future.

Given below is a sample of what I have tried:

Created a sub-function called `sub_func()` as below

```
def sub_func():
    # create presentation with 1 slide ------
    prs = Presentation()
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])

    # define chart data ---------------------
    chart_data = CategoryChartData()
    chart_data.categories = ['Zone1', 'Zone2', 'Zone3']
    chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))

    # add chart to slide --------------------
    x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
    slide.shapes.add_chart(
XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
    )
    prs.save('chart-00.pptx')
```

Saved the above to sub_func.py

Given below is my main function:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Inches
from sub_func import sub_func

def func():
    # create presentation with 1 slide ------
    prs = Presentation()
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])

    # define chart data ---------------------
    chart_data = CategoryChartData()
    chart_data.categories = ['East', 'West', 'Midwest']
    chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))

    # add chart to slide --------------------
    x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
    slide.shapes.add_chart(
XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
    )
    ##Calling the sub-function below

    sub_func()

    prs.save('chart-01.pptx')
```

This above generates a powerpoint file but does not execute the sub function. Could anyone advice as to where am I going wrong.

***Edited code:***

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Inches
from subfolder import func1
from pptx.parts.chart import ChartPart
from pptx.parts.embeddedpackage import EmbeddedXlsxPart

def func():
    # create presentation with 1 slide ------
    prs = Presentation()
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])

    # define chart data ---------------------
    chart_data = CategoryChartData()
    chart_data.categories = ['East', 'West', 'Midwest']
    chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))

    # add chart to slide --------------------
    x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
    slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy,chart_data)

    ##Calling the sub-function below

    def Add_Slide(self):
        xml_slides = prs.slides._sldIdLst
        xml_slides1 = prs1.slides._sldIdLst
        slides = list(xml_slides)
        slides1 = list(xml_slides1)
        xml_slides.append(xml_slides1)

    prs.save('chart-01.pptx')
```

Given below is the sub function:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Inches


def func1():
    # create presentation with 1 slide ------

    prs1 = Presentation()
    slide = prs1.slides.add_slide(prs1.slide_layouts[5])

    # define chart data ---------------------
    chart_data = CategoryChartData()
    chart_data.categories = ['East', 'West', 'Midwest']
    chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (100.2, 21.4, 16.7))

    # add chart to slide --------------------
    x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
    slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy,chart_data)
```

Using the above edited code, I see the main function gets executed but the sub function does not get executed, is it because it does not have a prs.save for the sub-function. Could you please advice..

Comment: Is there any error trackback ?

Comment: @PythonUser, nope the script runs fine without any errors. Just that the sub-function does not get executed.

Comment: How can we know the function does not execute? How do you know it? Could you provide more insight to avoid the need to guess what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

is `sub_func.py` in your python path? If it is just in your working directory, this will most likely result in a `ModuleNotFoundError`. You'll need to use a [relative import](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) then

```
from .sub_func import sub_func
```

---

If that is not the problem, but just the fact that it has no effect, then that is because you didn't tell it to have an effect. It creates a presentation with 1 slide, but doesn't save it. It doesn't get returned by the method, and the return value is not captured by a variable

Comment: I think the module is working fine, otherwise, he'd get an error. However, I agree with you. He is not saving the presentation. That's the problem.

Comment: @Maarten I have also tried saving the file in the sub-function as well but it still does not help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so issue is due to import statements.
You are re-initialling the presentation object again in sub_module.

```
prs = Presentation()
```

you can pass the `prs` object to `sub_func` like below and try if problem is getting solved

main function

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.util import Inches
from sub_func import sub_func

def func():
    # create presentation with 1 slide ------
    prs = Presentation()
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])

    # define chart data ---------------------
    chart_data = CategoryChartData()
    chart_data.categories = ['East', 'West', 'Midwest']
    chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))

    # add chart to slide --------------------
    x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
    slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy,chart_data)

    ##Calling the sub-function below

    sub_func(prs)

    prs.save('chart-01.pptx')
```

and in sub_func do the changes like below

```
def sub_func(prs):
    # create presentation with 1 slide ------
    # prs = Presentation() -------Remove this line
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])

    # define chart data ---------------------
    chart_data = CategoryChartData()
    chart_data.categories = ['Zone1', 'Zone2', 'Zone3']
    chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))

    # add chart to slide --------------------
    x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
    slide.shapes.add_chart(
XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data
    )
    prs.save('chart-00.pptx')
```

Comment: a better alternative might be to return `prs` instead of saving it to an arbitrary filename. You can additionaly also accept `prs`  as a parameter with default argument `None`, and do `prs = Presentation()` if `prs is None`. That way you won't break other uses of this sub_func

Comment: `Presentation()` is a constructor. Calling it again in sub_func() creates a new, separate presentation that can be manipulated and saved without affecting any other `Presentation` object (as long as it's saved with a distinct name, as it is). @MaartenFabré is on the right track here though, there's no obvious need to create a separate presentation unless you wanted each slide to be in its own .pptx file (which has its use cases but is uncommon).

Comment: @scanny , I came across some code online that tries to append slides from different files but it still does not help.. I have updated the initial post with this code. Could you please advice. Thanks..

Comment: That would be a separate question hello kee. Have a search on that topic and if you don't find what you're looking for post a new question focused on that topic specifically.

Answer (score -1):

```
from .sub_func import sub_func
```